# Python code for filling gaps for weekends and holidays in financial data when analyzing daily time series from regular calendar

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two daily time series, one for VIX market data and one for daily sentiment.  I need to align the two series by either padding the VIX data with null values for non-trading days or dropping non-trading days from the sentiment data.

Here is one data series file with data for each business day: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf656b9t0uctbqs/vixcurrent.csv?dl=0

Here is a second data series file were each row is a day on a regular calendar, and each column is a frequency of a positive sentiment word, starting from April 20, 2010 to August 1, 2018: 3025 days:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/55cvxl7irhaeqav/bpAFTDayPos.csv?dl=0

Comment: Could you show an example of both timeseries? Are those lists of dicts or some ORM objects wrapping databases, or some table-like objects? I think that 1 parameter per date and date-range of 1-2 weeks will be enough for both time series.

Comment: So far, I am planning the analysis and have not yet read the series into python.  Will post the series when I get them set up.  Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my question to include the two data files I need to merge and run time-series analysis, predicting the VIX from positive sentiment words.  I have another file like the positive sentiment one but for the negative sentiment words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) package. It has excellent support for time series data, including [NA/Null handling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html).

Methods for handling NA/Nulls include: backfill, forward fill, and pad.

Additionally, pandas has functionality to help you [handle holidays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-holiday).